# get list of modified files after git merge/git merge tool

Tags: git, merge, diff, mergetool

I have a master, branch1, and branch2.

I have used 'git merge' then 'git mergetool' to merge deltas (i.e. changes between master and branch2) into branch1.

Now I would like to identify all modified files under branch1 as the result of the above merge and copy all those modified files into a separate folder to send to someone.

What is the right way to do that?

Thanks!
p/s: my apology if this is too trivial question, I am new to GIT

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
git diff --name-only branch1^ branch1
# or :
git diff --name-status branch1^ branch1
```

---

Explaining :

1. In general, `git diff [commit1] [commit2]` will work with any two commits :

   ```
   git diff branch1 master
   git diff tag/v1.0 branch2
   git diff eacf32bb8 branch1
   # etc ...
   ```
2. With the `--name-only` or `--name-status` option, `git diff` will only display the list of modified files between the two commits (with `--name-status`, it will add a letter `A, M or D` in front of the filename, to indicate if it was `A`dded, `M`odified or `D`eleted)
3. When dealing with a merge commit, it has two parents :

   ```
   ...*--*--*--*--A---M  <- branch1
          \          /
           *--*--*--B
   ```

   in the sketch above, `A` is the first parent of `M`, and `B` its second parent.
   `branch1^` designates `A` (the first parent of `branch1`), `branch1^2` would designate `B` (the second parent of `branch1`).